# Flex : Styles vanishing when opening multiple HBoxes and appears back on scrolling down

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

My Flex application contains a set of Hbox,Vbox combination that is shown/hidden depending on users actions. There is an option provided to show all these containers as open(from their previous hidden state). At that point, the styles used in my page vanishes! The page becomes really lengthy and when I scroll down a bit, the styles reappear. If I scroll up again to a threshold point, all styles are lost and the page looks plain white! To bring the styles back, I need to scroll down again a bit...

Anyone knows why this is happening? Please provide your answers.[EDIT]

[Without style http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/1859/withoutstyle.jpg](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/1859/withoutstyle.jpg)
[with style http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/906/withstyle.jpg](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/906/withstyle.jpg)

The transition from image1 to image2 happens with a mild scroll down!

Comment: It sounds like a bug in your code. Could you post a snippet duplicating what you describe?

Comment: Its present only when the data present in the page is too high...In that case the page looks without the css applied and when I scroll a bit down everything is normal. I don't have access to the application now, will put a screenshot when I work on it again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the rendering of the style information is lagging behind the rendering of the data. That's why it 'catches up' if you wait but disappears again if you scroll.